# I can't understand why this is not working. maps is not loaded

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm pretty sure I've everything right. can you please check it for me. it gives me this error in the console:" Uncaught Error:  0 value is not correct for the function (translated from another language)"

```
function map_load() {
    var draw;

    var coords = Array(23.078412614088098, 57.33448100333726,
23.07858534246487, 57.33415377383744, 
23.078234950383354, 57.33415913825547, 
23.078190534420507, 57.334582927279826, 
23.07792403833525, 57.3352266574434);

    var s = -2;
    var triangleCoords = [];
    var coords_num = coords.length/2;

    for (i = 0; i < coords_num ; i++) {
        s += 2;
        triangleCoords[i] = google.maps.LatLng(coords[s],coords[s+1]);
    }

    var center1 = google.maps.LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]);

if (coords.length > 1) {
    draw = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: triangleCoords,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#FF0000",
        fillOpacity: 0.35
    });
} else {
    draw = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: triangleCoords,
        title:"your item location"
    });
}

    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 16,
      center: center1,
      panControl:false,
      streetViewControl:false,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
    draw.setMap(map);
}
```

Comment: What line are you getting the error on?

Comment: main.js obtained from [link](maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/ar_ALL/mapfiles/api-3/7/5)

Comment: where does `map_load` get called?

Comment: `<body onload="map_load()" >`

Comment: When I hit the API URL you linked I'm getting a 404

Comment: I can see that `<div id="map"></div>` turns gray but no map is loaded

Comment: that's what I got from the console. it's google stuff.

Comment: this is madness. @GregGuida I really appreciate you trying to help me.

Comment: what i'm saying is that you may have the wrong link to the maps api. isn't it http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false

Comment: @GregGuida it's correct but the link differs when you wanna load the content in another language. thank you so much for trying to help me ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made the same mistake twice, missing the word 'new' to construct your LatLng objects.

```
 triangleCoords[i] = google.maps.LatLng(coords[s],coords[s+1]);
```

should be

```
 triangleCoords[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[s],coords[s+1]);
```

Also happens at center1

```
var center1 = google.maps.LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]);
```

should be

```
var center1 = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I really got mad with code because I reviewed it many times. I really appreciate your help. thank you again.